# Is it possible to use variable subsitution for mongodb.conf

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to use variable subsitution in mongodb.conf like

```
dbpath=${mongodb_home}/db
keyFile=${mongodb_home}/key/keyfile
logpath=${mongodb_home}/log/mongodb.log
```

I understand that this could be done through mongod command line as parameters, but I am interested in containing everything in the configuration so I can run mongodb using

```
mongod -f etc/mongodb.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do variable substitution in the mongodb.conf file.